# Upload file to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have setup S3 bucket in US West i.e N. California

My Pool-ID start with "us-east-1:*****"

I have following code to upload file on my bucket named AWS_BUCKET_NAME

```
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USWest1, identityPoolId: AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    let uploadingFileURL = videoURL
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest?.bucket = AWS_BUCKET_NAME
    uploadRequest?.key = fileName
    uploadRequest?.body = uploadingFileURL
    uploadRequest?.contentType = "video/mp4"

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest!).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread())
    { (task) -> Any? in
        if task.error == nil
        {
            return nil
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: task.error))")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Mostly it successfully upload the video files. But sometimes its giving error like bellow

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x608001a53c50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://cognito-identity.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://cognito-identity.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}

Now if i change the regionType in AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider to USEast1 or some other and try again then its again give me same error but after that if i set "USWest1" region again then its working again. It will continue to work successful for 5-6 times or sometimes even more. But again after sometime it generating same error.

One more thing, with same pool id and region, Its working fine in android. only facing this issue in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to me like it's either DNS resolution related, or AWS is having issues. How long has this been happening? Is there anything about it that you can consistently reproduce?

Comment: This is since i have implemented. i.e about 5 days. it is not consistent. Its random issue.

Comment: Can you try testing with a different DNS server to see if the problems resolve?

Comment: Have tried with 3 Different Wi-Fi, Mobile Data, LAN. Still same issue.

Comment: Can you try with a different device, or have someone else try in a different location?

Comment: Have tried in different devices. But not tried with different location.

Comment: This is not DNS related, @brandonscript... there isn't a us-west-1 [endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_identity_region) for Cognito.  The question seems to be why this code tries to access a nonexistent endpoint, or why does it ever work at all...

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution for this. This is not proper answer but it may help someone else who are facing such issue.

```
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
```

After [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot)'s comment, i have checked by changing Region one after another. Finally i am creating `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider` with .USEast1 and configuring `AWSServiceConfiguration` with .USWest1 and it is working now.

I don't know the reason behind but probably we need to configure `AWSServiceConfiguration` with the region of bucket we are using.